# Unable to make it work with OAuth from AWS-EC2 but doable in localhost

Tags: amazon-ec2, oauth, google-signin

I followed every instructions from this site [Google Dev Console site](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)
and my web app was working well in http://localhost. No issues.

Now I deployed the web app in the AWS-EC2 server. I also added the Javascript Origins to show my 'subdomain.domain.com'.  Upon hitting the button 'Google Login' from webapp on subdomain.domain.com, the google-authentication is not working ; shows the below error, *where XX.YY.ZZ.AA is my AWS EC2 instance IP*;

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
>
> Request Details
>   redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/XX.YY.ZZ.AA?id=auth736964
>   response_type=permission id_token scope=email profile openid
>   openid.realm=
>   client_id=625394219770-q0qilkfl05m2fortt25j2j63e2dn6c1r.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   ss_domain=http://XX.YY.ZZ.AA fetch_basic_profile=true gsiwebsdk=2
>   That’s all we know.

I am asking for help on how to resolve this. Is it a EC2 forward issue, because the google error is not showing my subdomain.domain.com instead EC2-ip address. or something else?